# How can i show labels inside a pie chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I basically want to have the labels for my PieChart both below as a "legend" and inside the graph. How can I do it? Also is there a way to get rid of the deciaml number in the values?

Thanks

Here is my current configuration. I want to get "Foot" or "Still" inside the graph too (well, not inside but under the  value right outside the graph)

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdTUN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Create entries in a following way:

```
ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(floatValue, StringLabel));
```

after that you need to show values by doing following:

```
pieDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to display the label inside the PieChart:

```
pieChart = view.findViewById(R.id.piechart)

pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(true)
```